# XSLT for-each mixing up values which are not being concatenated correctly and also not respecting tag's maximum size

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach

I really need some help with XSL since I am new to it.

Actually, there can be various tags of `<RmtInf>` based on the number of invoices run, but following requirements, we decided to make only one parent tag of `<RmtInf>` to appear with only one `<Ref>` tag also, but consisting of concatenated values of the multiple invoice numbers ran, separated by delimiter `/`.  [Maximum size of `<Ref>` should be 35]

```
<RmtInf>
    <Strd>
        <CdtrRefInf>
            <Tp>
                <CdOrPrtry>
                    <Cd>TEST</Cd>
                </CdOrPrtry>
                <Issr>TEST NAME</Issr>
            </Tp>
            <Ref>TestSpecial-Char</Ref>
        </CdtrRefInf>
    </Strd>
</RmtInf>
```

If invoice `Ref` number run was `TestSpecial-Char` and `TestSpecial-Char2`, then the `<Ref>` tag should have been as follows:

```
<Ref>TestSpecial-Char/ TestSpecial-Char2</Ref>
```

However, when running for multiple invoices, its output is as follows:

```
<RmtInf>
    <Strd>
        <CdtrRefInf>
            <Tp>
                <CdOrPrtry>
                    <Cd>TEST</Cd>
                </CdOrPrtry>
                <Issr>TEST NAME</Issr>
            </Tp>
            <Ref>Test Second RefTestSecondRef/TestChar</Ref>
        </CdtrRefInf>
    </Strd>
</RmtInf>
```

Two `<Ref>`: `Test Second Ref` and `TestChar`, but here the `Test Second Ref` has been repeated twice.

When we ran for 3 invoices, three `<Ref>`: `TestRun3Inv-a`, `TestRun3Inv-b` and `TestRun3Inv-c`, and as you can see in the output, it is mixing the different invoice numbers together and not respecting the limit of 35 characters:

```
<RmtInf>
    <Strd>
        <CdtrRefInf>
            <Tp>
                <CdOrPrtry>
                    <Cd>TEST</Cd>
                </CdOrPrtry>
                <Issr>TEST NAME</Issr>
            </Tp>
            <Ref>TestRun3Inv-a/ TestRun3Inv-bTestRun3Inv-a/TestRun3Inv-b/TestR</Ref>
        </CdtrRefInf>
    </Strd>
</RmtInf>
```

In the XSL, we added the following piece of codes:

```
<xsl:template name="substring-before-last">
    <!--passed template parameter -->
    <xsl:param name="list" />
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($list, $delimiter)">
            <!-- get everything in front of the first delimiter -->
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($list,$delimiter)" />
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains(substring-after($list,$delimiter),$delimiter)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter" />
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:call-template name="substring-before-last">
                <!-- store anything left in another variable -->
                <xsl:with-param name="list" select="substring-after($list,$delimiter)" />
                <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="sanitize">
    <xsl:param name="str" />
    <xsl:value-of select="translate($str, translate($str, '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz&apos.,+?/():-', ''), '')" />
</xsl:template>
```

It is called as follows:

```
<Ref>
    <xsl:variable name="concatstring">
        <xsl:for-each select="DocumentPayable">
            <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
                <xsl:text>/ </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not(DocumentNumber/UniqueRemittanceIdentifier/Number='')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(DocumentNumber/UniqueRemittanceIdentifier/Number, 1, 35)" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(DocumentNumber/ReferenceNumber, 1, 35)" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="concatstringfinal">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($concatstring,1,35)" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:call-template name="substring-before-last">
        <xsl:with-param name="list" select="normalize-space($concatstringfinal)" />
        <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="'/'" />
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:call-template name="sanitize">
        <xsl:with-param name="str" select="($concatstringfinal)" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</Ref>
```

Could you please help? Thanking you in advance.

Input:

```
<RmtInf>
<Cd>TEST</Cd>
<Issr>Test Name</Issr>
<Ref>TestSpecialChar</Ref>
</RmtInf>
<RmtInf>
<Cd>TEST</Cd>
<Issr>Test Name</Issr>
<Ref>TestSpecialChar2</Ref>
</RmtInf>
<RmtInf>
<Cd>TEST</Cd>
<Issr>Test Name</Issr>
<Ref>TestSpecialChar3</Ref>
</RmtInf>
```

Required Output:

```
<RmtInf>
<Strd>
    <CdtrRefInf>
        <Tp>
            <CdOrPrtry>
                <Cd>TEST</Cd>
            </CdOrPrtry>
            <Issr>Test Name</Issr>
        </Tp>
        <Ref>TestSpecialChar/T/</Ref> <!--Only 35 characters-->
    </CdtrRefInf>
</Strd>
</RmtInf>
```

Sorry, I was trying to simplify it, but then I having issues making the XSL valid.

Sample Input XML:

```
<PositivePayDataExtract>
<OutboundPayment>
    <RecordHistory>
        <CreatedBy>CVBUYER01</CreatedBy>
        <CreationDate>2016-06-14T02:08:17</CreationDate>
        <LastUpdateDate>2016-06-14T02:08:38</LastUpdateDate>
        <LastUpdateLogin>35393B21F75FB4C1E0531DB0F20A9896</LastUpdateLogin>
        <LastUpdatedBy>CVBUYER01</LastUpdatedBy>
    </RecordHistory>
    <PaymentSourceInfo>
        <ApplicationInternalID>200</ApplicationInternalID>
        <ApplicationName>AP</ApplicationName>
        <PaymentServiceRequestID>112583</PaymentServiceRequestID>
        <FunctionalCategory>
            <Code>PAYABLES_DISB</Code>
            <Meaning>Payables disbursements</Meaning>
        </FunctionalCategory>
        <PayerOrganization>
            <OrganizationInternalID>204</OrganizationInternalID>
            <OrganizationType>
                <Code>OPERATING_UNIT</Code>
                <Meaning>Business unit</Meaning>
            </OrganizationType>
            <OrganizationName>Vision Operations</OrganizationName>
        </PayerOrganization>
        <EmployeePaymentFlag>N</EmployeePaymentFlag>
    </PaymentSourceInfo>
    <PaymentNumber>
        <DocCategory/>
        <SequenceName/>
        <SequenceValue/>
        <PaymentReferenceNumber>2330</PaymentReferenceNumber>
        <CheckNumber>123153</CheckNumber>
    </PaymentNumber>
    <PaymentDate>2016-06-14</PaymentDate>
    <PaymentDueDate>2016-06-14</PaymentDueDate>
    <MaturityDate/>
    <AnticipatedValueDate/>
    <PaymentStatus>
        <Code>ISSUED</Code>
        <Meaning>Printed</Meaning>
    </PaymentStatus>
    <Payee>
        <PartyInternalID>299436</PartyInternalID>
        <PartyNumber>50665</PartyNumber>
        <Name>GE Capital</Name>
        <TaxRegistrationNumber>12345678</TaxRegistrationNumber>
        <LegalEntityRegistrationNumber/>
        <AlternateName/>
        <PersonInfo>
            <TownOfBirth/>
            <BirthDate/>
            <CountryOfBirth/>
        </PersonInfo>
        <SupplierNumber>1001</SupplierNumber>
        <Address>
            <AddressInternalID>2</AddressInternalID>
            <AddressLine1>44 Old Ridgebury Road</AddressLine1>
            <AddressLine2/>
            <AddressLine3/>
            <AddressLine4/>
            <City>DANBURY</City>
            <County>FAIRFIELD</County>
            <State>CT</State>
            <Country>US</Country>
            <ISO3DigitCountry>USA</ISO3DigitCountry>
            <CountryName>United States</CountryName>
            <PostalCode>06810-5105</PostalCode>
            <AddressName>DANBURY</AddressName>
            <AlternateAddressName>GE CAPITAL</AlternateAddressName>
            <PreFormattedConcatenatedAddress>44 Old Ridgebury Road, , , DANBURY, CT, US, 06810-5105</PreFormattedConcatenatedAddress>
            <PreFormattedMailingAddress>44 Old Ridgebury Road, , , DANBURY, CT, US, 06810-5105</PreFormattedMailingAddress>
        </Address>
        <ContactInfo>
            <ContactLocators>
                <PhoneNumber/>
                <FaxNumber/>
                <EmailAddress/>
                <Website/>
            </ContactLocators>
        </ContactInfo>
        <RemitAdviceDeliveryMethod>PRINTED</RemitAdviceDeliveryMethod>
    </Payee>
    <SupplierorParty>
        <PartyInternalID>299436</PartyInternalID>
        <PartyNumber>50665</PartyNumber>
        <Name>GE Capital</Name>
        <TaxRegistrationNumber>12345678</TaxRegistrationNumber>
        <LegalEntityRegistrationNumber/>
        <AlternateName/>
        <PersonInfo>
            <TownOfBirth/>
            <BirthDate/>
            <CountryOfBirth/>
        </PersonInfo>
        <SupplierNumber>1001</SupplierNumber>
        <Address>
            <AddressInternalID>2</AddressInternalID>
            <AddressLine1>44 Old Ridgebury Road</AddressLine1>
            <AddressLine2/>
            <AddressLine3/>
            <AddressLine4/>
            <City>DANBURY</City>
            <County>FAIRFIELD</County>
            <State>CT</State>
            <Country>US</Country>
            <ISO3DigitCountry>USA</ISO3DigitCountry>
            <CountryName>United States</CountryName>
            <PostalCode>06810-5105</PostalCode>
            <AddressName>DANBURY</AddressName>
            <AlternateAddressName>GE CAPITAL</AlternateAddressName>
            <PreFormattedConcatenatedAddress>44 Old Ridgebury Road, , , DANBURY, CT, US, 06810-5105</PreFormattedConcatenatedAddress>
            <PreFormattedMailingAddress>44 Old Ridgebury Road, , , DANBURY, CT, US, 06810-5105</PreFormattedMailingAddress>
        </Address>
        <ContactInfo>
            <ContactLocators>
                <PhoneNumber/>
                <FaxNumber/>
                <EmailAddress/>
                <Website/>
            </ContactLocators>
        </ContactInfo>
        <RemitAdviceDeliveryMethod>PRINTED</RemitAdviceDeliveryMethod>
    </SupplierorParty>
    <PayeeBankAccount>
        <BankAccountInternalID>1443</BankAccountInternalID>
        <BankName>Bank of America</BankName>
        <AlternateBankName/>
        <BankNumber>163281189</BankNumber>
        <BranchInternalID>300540</BranchInternalID>
        <BranchName>New York</BranchName>
        <AlternateBranchName/>
        <BranchNumber>122000247</BranchNumber>
        <BankCode/>
        <BankAccountName>BofA-204</BankAccountName>
        <AlternateBankAccountName/>
        <BankAccountNumber>10271-17621-619</BankAccountNumber>
        <MaskedBankAccountNumber>XXXXXXXXXXX-619</MaskedBankAccountNumber>
        <UserEnteredBankAccountNumber>10271-17621-619</UserEnteredBankAccountNumber>
        <BankAccountSuffix/>
        <SwiftCode/>
        <IBANNumber/>
        <MaskedIBANNumber/>
        <CheckDigits/>
        <BankAccountType>
            <Code/>
            <Meaning/>
        </BankAccountType>
        <BankAccountCurrency>
            <Code/>
        </BankAccountCurrency>
        <BankAddress>
            <AddressInternalID>24980</AddressInternalID>
            <AddressLine1>6788 Wall Street</AddressLine1>
            <AddressLine2/>
            <AddressLine3/>
            <AddressLine4/>
            <City>NEW YORK</City>
            <County>NEW YORK</County>
            <State>NY</State>
            <Province/>
            <Country>US</Country>
            <ISO3DigitCountry>USA</ISO3DigitCountry>
            <CountryName>United States</CountryName>
            <PostalCode>05443</PostalCode>
            <PreFormattedConcatenatedAddress>6788 Wall Street/NEW YORK, NY 05443</PreFormattedConcatenatedAddress>
            <PreFormattedMailingAddress>6788 Wall Street/NEW YORK, NY 05443</PreFormattedMailingAddress>
        </BankAddress>
        <PrimaryOwner>
            <Name>GE Capital</Name>
        </PrimaryOwner>
        <FactorAccount>
            <Code>N</Code>
            <Meaning>No</Meaning>
        </FactorAccount>
        <BranchDescriptiveFlexField/>
    </PayeeBankAccount>
    <Payer>
        <PartyInternalID>299158</PartyInternalID>
        <PartyNumber>50387</PartyNumber>
        <Name>Vision Operations</Name>
        <PartyType>
            <Code/>
            <Meaning/>
        </PartyType>
        <TaxRegistrationNumber>4567890</TaxRegistrationNumber>
        <LegalEntityRegistrationNumber>SYS12125</LegalEntityRegistrationNumber>
        <LegalEntityInternalID>204</LegalEntityInternalID>
        <LegalEntityName>Vision Operations</LegalEntityName>
        <Address>
            <AddressInternalID>20795</AddressInternalID>
            <AddressLine1>475 Park Avenue</AddressLine1>
            <AddressLine2/>
            <AddressLine3/>
            <City>New York</City>
            <County>New York</County>
            <State>NY</State>
            <Province/>
            <Country>US</Country>
            <ISO3DigitCountry>USA</ISO3DigitCountry>
            <CountryName>United States</CountryName>
            <PostalCode>10022</PostalCode>
            <PreFormattedConcatenatedAddress>475 Park Avenue, NEW YORK, NY 10022</PreFormattedConcatenatedAddress>
            <PreFormattedMailingAddress>475 Park Avenue, NEW YORK, NY 10022</PreFormattedMailingAddress>
            <AddressName>V1 Ship Site A</AddressName>
        </Address>
        <ContactInfo>
            <ContactLocators>
                <PhoneNumber/>
                <FaxNumber/>
                <EmailAddress/>
                <Website/>
            </ContactLocators>
        </ContactInfo>
    </Payer>
    <BankAccount>
        <BankAccountInternalID>11000</BankAccountInternalID>
        <BankName>Bank of America</BankName>
        <AlternateBankName/>
        <BankNumber>163281189</BankNumber>
        <BranchInternalID>300540</BranchInternalID>
        <BranchName>New York</BranchName>
        <AlternateBranchName/>
        <BranchNumber>122000247</BranchNumber>
        <BankAccountName>BofA-204A</BankAccountName>
        <AlternateBankAccountName/>
        <BankAccountNumber>5486173210</BankAccountNumber>
        <MaskedBankAccountNumber>XXXXXX3210</MaskedBankAccountNumber>
        <UserEnteredBankAccountNumber>5486173210</UserEnteredBankAccountNumber>
        <BankAccountSuffix/>
        <SwiftCode/>
        <IBANNumber/>
        <CheckDigits/>
        <BankAccountType>
            <Code/>
            <Meaning/>
        </BankAccountType>
        <BankAccountCurrency>
            <Code>USD</Code>
        </BankAccountCurrency>
        <BankAddress>
            <AddressInternalID>24980</AddressInternalID>
            <AddressLine1>6788 Wall Street</AddressLine1>
            <AddressLine2/>
            <AddressLine3/>
            <AddressLine4/>
            <City>NEW YORK</City>
            <County>NEW YORK</County>
            <State>NY</State>
            <Province/>
            <Country>US</Country>
            <ISO3DigitCountry>USA</ISO3DigitCountry>
            <CountryName>United States</CountryName>
            <PostalCode>05443</PostalCode>
            <PreFormattedConcatenatedAddress>6788 Wall Street/NEW YORK, NY 05443</PreFormattedConcatenatedAddress>
            <PreFormattedMailingAddress>6788 Wall Street/NEW YORK, NY 05443</PreFormattedMailingAddress>
        </BankAddress>
        <BranchDescriptiveFlexField/>
        <FederalBankAccountInfo>
            <FederalRFCIdentifier/>
            <FederalAgencyLocationCode/>
            <FederalAbbreviatedAgencyCode/>
            <FederalEmployerIdentificationNumber/>
        </FederalBankAccountInfo>
        <EFTUserNumber>
            <AccountLevelEFTNumber/>
            <BranchLevelEFTNumber>011001331</BranchLevelEFTNumber>
        </EFTUserNumber>
    </BankAccount>
    <Beneficiary>
        <Name>GE Capital</Name>
    </Beneficiary>
    <PaymentAmount>
        <Value>1000</Value>
        <Currency>
            <Code>USD</Code>
            <Name>US Dollar</Name>
        </Currency>
    </PaymentAmount>
    <PaymentAmountText>One Thousand Dollars And  Zero Cents*****</PaymentAmountText>
    <PaymentMethod>
        <PaymentMethodInternalID>CHECK</PaymentMethodInternalID>
        <PaymentMethodName>Check</PaymentMethodName>
        <PaymentMethodFormatValue>CHECK</PaymentMethodFormatValue>
    </PaymentMethod>
    <PayAlongFlag>N</PayAlongFlag>
    <SettlementPriority>
        <Code>NORMAL</Code>
        <Meaning>Normal</Meaning>
    </SettlementPriority>
    <AmountWithheld>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <Currency>
            <Code>USD</Code>
        </Currency>
    </AmountWithheld>
    <DiscountTaken>
        <Amount>
            <Value>0</Value>
            <Currency>
                <Code>USD</Code>
            </Currency>
        </Amount>
    </DiscountTaken>
    <BankCharges>
        <BankChargeBearer>
            <Code>BEN</Code>
            <Meaning>Payee</Meaning>
        </BankChargeBearer>
        <Amount>
            <Value>0</Value>
            <Currency>
                <Code>USD</Code>
            </Currency>
        </Amount>
    </BankCharges>
    <DeliveryChannel>
        <Code>DELIVERY_CHANNEL_1</Code>
        <Meaning>Delivery Channel 1</Meaning>
        <FormatValue>Delivery Channel 1 Alias</FormatValue>
    </DeliveryChannel>
    <ServiceLevel>
        <Code>BKTR</Code>
        <Meaning>Book transaction</Meaning>
        <FormatValue/>
    </ServiceLevel>
    <PaymentReason>
        <Code>US_FV_M</Code>
        <Meaning>Miscellaneous PPD</Meaning>
        <FormatValue>M</FormatValue>
    </PaymentReason>
    <PaymentReasonComments>Site Danburry PMT Reason comment</PaymentReasonComments>
    <RemittanceMessage/>
    <RemittanceMessage/>
    <RemittanceMessage/>
    <BankInstruction>
        <BankInstructionCode>INSTRUCTION1</BankInstructionCode>
        <Meaning>Instruction 1</Meaning>
        <FormatValue>INSTRUCTION1_ALIAS</FormatValue>
    </BankInstruction>
    <BankInstruction>
        <BankInstructionCode>INSTRUCTION2</BankInstructionCode>
        <Meaning>Instruction 2</Meaning>
        <FormatValue>INSTRUCTION2_ALIAS</FormatValue>
    </BankInstruction>
    <BankInstructionDetails>Site Danburry Bank Inst Dtls</BankInstructionDetails>
    <PaymentTextMessage>Site Danburry PMT Text Msg1</PaymentTextMessage>
    <PaymentTextMessage>Site Danburry PMT Text Msg2</PaymentTextMessage>
    <PaymentTextMessage>Site Danburry PMT Text Msg3</PaymentTextMessage>
    <PaymentDetails/>
    <RegulatoryReporting>
        <DeclarationFlag>N</DeclarationFlag>
        <Amount>
            <Value>0</Value>
            <Currency>
                <Code/>
            </Currency>
        </Amount>
    </RegulatoryReporting>
    <FederalPaymentInfo>
        <FederalAllotmentCode/>
        <FederalOffsetEligibilityFlag/>
        <FederalAccountingSymbol/>
    </FederalPaymentInfo>
    <LogicalGrouping>
        <PaymentInformationAmountTotal/>
        <PaymentInformationTotal/>
        <LogicalGroupReference/>
    </LogicalGrouping>
    <DocumentPayableCount>1</DocumentPayableCount>
    <DocumentPayable>
        <RecordHistory>
            <CreatedBy>CVSUPPA01</CreatedBy>
            <CreationDate>2016-06-14T02:08:17</CreationDate>
            <LastUpdateDate>2016-06-14T02:08:17</LastUpdateDate>
            <LastUpdateLogin>3539839C3E771F66E0531DB0F20ADC84</LastUpdateLogin>
            <LastUpdatedBy>CVSUPPA01</LastUpdatedBy>
        </RecordHistory>
        <InvoiceBusinessUnit>
            <InvoiceBusinessUnitId>204</InvoiceBusinessUnitId>
            <InvoiceBusinessUnitType>
                <Code>OPERATING_UNIT</Code>
                <Meaning>Business unit</Meaning>
            </InvoiceBusinessUnitType>
            <InvoiceBusinessUnitName>Vision Operations</InvoiceBusinessUnitName>
        </InvoiceBusinessUnit>
        <DocumentNumber>
            <DocumentInternalIDSegment1>300100202530180</DocumentInternalIDSegment1>
            <DocumentInternalIDSegment2>300100202530169</DocumentInternalIDSegment2>
            <DocumentInternalIDSegment3>1</DocumentInternalIDSegment3>
            <DocumentInternalIDSegment4>300100202530181</DocumentInternalIDSegment4>
            <DocumentInternalIDSegment5/>
            <ApplicationInternalID>200</ApplicationInternalID>
            <ApplicationDocumentSubType>PAYABLES_DOC</ApplicationDocumentSubType>
            <ApplicationUniqueInternalID>300100202530180</ApplicationUniqueInternalID>
            <ReferenceNumber>ki14jun1601</ReferenceNumber>
            <UniqueRemittanceIdentifier>
                <Number/>
                <CheckDigit/>
            </UniqueRemittanceIdentifier>
            <DocCategory/>
            <SequenceName/>
            <SequenceValue/>
        </DocumentNumber>
        <PONumber/>
        <DocumentStatus>
            <Code>PAYMENT_CREATED</Code>
            <Meaning>Payment created</Meaning>
        </DocumentStatus>
        <DocumentDate>2016-06-14</DocumentDate>
        <DocumentCreationDate>2016-06-14T02:08:17.000000</DocumentCreationDate>
        <PaymentDueDate>2016-06-14</PaymentDueDate>
        <DocumentType>
            <Code>STANDARD</Code>
            <Meaning>Standard</Meaning>
        </DocumentType>
        <DocumentDescription/>
        <ExpenseReportCreditCardNumber/>
        <EmployeePaymentFlag>N</EmployeePaymentFlag>
        <TotalDocumentAmount>
            <Value>1000</Value>
            <Currency>
                <Code>USD</Code>
            </Currency>
        </TotalDocumentAmount>
        <PaymentAmount>
            <Value>1000</Value>
            <Currency>
                <Code>USD</Code>
            </Currency>
        </PaymentAmount>
        <PaymentAmountinDocumentCurrency>
            <Value>1000</Value>
            <Currency>
                <Code>USD</Code>
            </Currency>
        </PaymentAmountinDocumentCurrency>
        <PayAloneFlag>N</PayAloneFlag>
        <SettlementPriority>
            <Code>NORMAL</Code>
            <Meaning>Normal</Meaning>
        </SettlementPriority>
        <AmountWithheld>
            <Value>0</Value>
            <Currency>
                <Code>USD</Code>
            </Currency>
        </AmountWithheld>
        <AmoutWithheldinDocumentCurrency>
            <Value>0</Value>
            <Currency>
                <Code>USD</Code>
            </Currency>
        </AmoutWithheldinDocumentCurrency>
        <DiscountTaken>
            <Amount>
                <Value>0</Value>
                <Currency>
                    <Code>USD</Code>
                </Currency>
            </Amount>
            <DiscountDate/>
        </DiscountTaken>
        <DiscountTakeninDocumentCurrency>
            <Amount>
                <Value>0</Value>
                <Currency>
                    <Code>USD</Code>
                </Currency>
            </Amount>
        </DiscountTakeninDocumentCurrency>
        <BankCharges>
            <BankChargeBearer>
                <Code>BEN</Code>
                <Meaning>Payee</Meaning>
            </BankChargeBearer>
        </BankCharges>
        <DeliveryChannel>
            <Code>DELIVERY_CHANNEL_1</Code>
            <Meaning>Delivery Channel 1</Meaning>
            <FormatValue>Delivery Channel 1 Alias</FormatValue>
        </DeliveryChannel>
        <PaymentReason>
            <Code>US_FV_M</Code>
            <Meaning>Miscellaneous PPD</Meaning>
            <FormatValue>M</FormatValue>
        </PaymentReason>
        <PaymentReasonComments>Site Danburry PMT Reason comment</PaymentReasonComments>
        <RemittanceMessage/>
        <RemittanceMessage/>
        <RemittanceMessage/>
        <Charge>
            <TotalDocumentChargeAmount>
                <Value>0</Value>
                <Currency>
                    <Code>USD</Code>
                </Currency>
            </TotalDocumentChargeAmount>
        </Charge>
        <TotalDocumentTaxAmount>
            <Value>0</Value>
            <Currency>
                <Code>USD</Code>
            </Currency>
        </TotalDocumentTaxAmount>
        <CreditAmountApplied>
            <Value>0</Value>
            <Currency>
                <Code>USD</Code>
            </Currency>
        </CreditAmountApplied>
        <InterestAmountApplied>
            <Value>0</Value>
            <Currency>
                <Code>USD</Code>
            </Currency>
        </InterestAmountApplied>
        <InterestRate>0</InterestRate>
        <DocumentPayableLine>
            <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
            <PONumber/>
            <ConsumptionAdviceNumber/>
            <LineType>
                <Code>ITEM</Code>
                <Meaning/>
            </LineType>
            <LineDescription/>
            <LineGrossAmount>
                <Value>1000</Value>
                <Currency>
                    <Code>USD</Code>
                </Currency>
            </LineGrossAmount>
            <UnitPrice>0</UnitPrice>
            <Quantity/>
            <UnitOfMeasure>
                <Code/>
                <Meaning/>
            </UnitOfMeasure>
            <Tax>
                <TaxCode/>
                <TaxRate>0</TaxRate>
            </Tax>
        </DocumentPayableLine>
        <SrcDocDescriptiveFlexField>
            <AttributeCategory>One-Time</AttributeCategory>
        </SrcDocDescriptiveFlexField>
        <SrcDocGlobalDescriptiveFlexField>
        </SrcDocGlobalDescriptiveFlexField>
    </DocumentPayable>
    <InvoicingLegalEntity>
        <LegalEntityId>204</LegalEntityId>
        <Name>Vision Operations</Name>
        <LegalEntityRegistrationNumber>SYS12125</LegalEntityRegistrationNumber>
        <Address>
            <Country>US</Country>
            <PostalCode>10022</PostalCode>
            <City>New York</City>
            <County>New York</County>
            <State>NY</State>
            <Province/>
            <AddressLine1>475 Park Avenue</AddressLine1>
            <AddressLine2/>
            <AddressLine3/>
        </Address>
    </InvoicingLegalEntity>
</OutboundPayment>
```

Simplified Input XML:
[Simplified Input XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkh7l.png)

Normally for the Cd, Issr and Ref, it is retrieved as follows:

```
Cd --> "SCOR"
Issr --> Payee/Name"
Ref - > DocumentNumber/UniqueRemittanceIdentifier/Number or 
DocumentNumber/ReferenceNumber
```

Please note with the for each I was able to do the required formatting except that the the  is appearing only once instead of multiple times, when required.

Please let me know if you require any further information. Sorry for the inconveniences caused. Thank you.

Comment: Can you share the input XML that is used for transformation? The XML samples shared look like they are the output XMLs.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the shared input XML and assuming that you are using **XSLT 1.0**,

```
<RmtInf>
    <Cd>TEST</Cd>
    <Issr>Test Name</Issr>
    <Ref>TestSpecialChar</Ref>
</RmtInf>
<RmtInf>
    <Cd>TEST</Cd>
    <Issr>Test Name</Issr>
    <Ref>TestSpecialChar2</Ref>
</RmtInf>
<RmtInf>
    <Cd>TEST</Cd>
    <Issr>Test Name</Issr>
    <Ref>TestSpecialChar3</Ref>
</RmtInf>
```

a better option is to use [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) to group all the `Cd` elements by their value (`TEST` in this case) and then prepare the `Ref` element value. Grouping is a more optimal approach as compared to using `for-each` loops.

Define a key to group the elements

```
<xsl:key name="keyCd" match="RmtInf" use="Cd" />
```

Match the grouped template

```
<xsl:template match="RmtInf[generate-id() = generate-id(key('keyCd', Cd)[1])]">
```

Value of the `Cd` element and `Issr` element in the output will be

```
<Cd><xsl:value-of select="key('keyCd', Cd)/Cd" /></Cd>
<Issr><xsl:value-of select="key('keyCd', Cd)/Issr" /></Issr>
```

Loop through the grouped elements and concatenate the value of `Ref` and store it in a variable.

```
<xsl:variable name="strRef">
    <xsl:for-each select="key('keyCd', Cd)">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(Ref, '/')" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Check for the length of the variable and accordingly display it.

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="string-length($strRef) &gt; 35">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($strRef, 1, 35)" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$strRef" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

The working example can be found here -> https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiJv

If you can upgrade to **XSLT 2.0**, the code will be much shorter as grouping has been enhanced considerably and `<xsl:for-each-group>` can be used.

Comment: Hello Thank you very much for the above. However, I am still stuck.That is, normally in the XSL, we retrieved the values of <Cd>, <Issr> and <Ref> with codes like <Issr><xsl:value-of select="substring(Payee/Name, 1, 35)"/></Issr> or Cd is hardcoded, [<Cd>SCOR</Cd>]. How do I map it on the above answer provided?

Comment: This looks like a change to the input XML. Please update the question with the input XML.